# print table description into text file

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to print out mysql table description into a text file for example ? 
I would like to see the format is done as 
when I type

```
describe tableName;
```

I would like to do this using windows command line

Comment: From the command line: `mysql -e "DESCRIBE tableName;" -uuser -p > ouputfile.txt`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+output+to+file

Comment: THen add some kind of "use DATABASE;" or "describe DATABASE.tableName".

Comment: Should have been: `mysql -e "DESCRIBE tableName;" -uuser -p databasename > ouputfile.txt`  I left out the databasename argument.